# reCAPTCHA Error: Invalid API parameter(s). Try reloading the page

Tags: recaptcha

i keep getting reCAPTCHA Error: Invalid API parameter(s). Try reloading the page. Whenever i try to "solve"  reCAPTCHA V2...
This the only thing i found on internet about it, and it didn't help me a bit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/computers/comments/f4w0wf/recaptcha_error_invalid_api_parameters_try/
I got the same problem... Couldn't even pass the stackoverflow's one. Any help is useful :) [Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIHv.jpg)

Comment: Same problem i faced, i couldn't find what it is exactly,but i added VPN extension in crome and then problem got solve u should try same

Answer (score 8):

If you are comfortable in the registry: 
open run: `regedit`
and Try this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

On the right side, you'll find a file named:

"`ProxySettingsPerUse`" or "`Default`"

Click it and change its value to "1" (obviously without the " ").
Then you accept.

From:
Gabriel Lobo  on https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/34982026?hl=en
 A few responses said it worked for them.

It worked for me too